# Understanding lldb in Xcode

Tags: c, xcode

Why is this outputting lldb?

```
int main()
{
    //creating an array
    float numbers_geeks_love[3];
    numbers_geeks_love[0] = 3.1415;
    //Movies_I_Love[1] = 14.5;
    //Movies_I_Love[2] = 21.5;
    printf("PI %f/n", numbers_geeks_love[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code outputs `PI 3.141500/n` for me. (I think you meant `\n` for new line, not `/n`)

Comment: [lldb](http://lldb.llvm.org/) is the debugger used by xcode, I think it just print its name first

Comment: `lldb` is the debugger.